# Getting notification that the serial port is ready to be read from

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, hardware, embedded-linux

I have to write a C++ application that reads from the serial port byte by byte. This is an important need as it is receiving messages over radio transmission using modbus and the end of transmission is defined by 3.5 character length duration so I MUST be able to get the message byte by byte. The current system utilises DOS to do this which uses hardware interrupts. We wish to transfer to use Linux as the OS for this software, but we lack expertise in this area. I have tried a number of things to do this - firstly using polling with non-blocking read, using select with very short timeout values, setting the size of the read buffer of the serial port to one byte, and even using a signal handler on SIGIO, but none of these things provide quite what I require. My boss informs me that the DOS application we currently run uses hardware interrupts to get notification when there is something available to read from the serial port and that the hardware is accessible directly. Is there any way that I can get this functionality from a user space Linux application? Could I do this if I wrote a custom driver (despite never having done this before and having close to zero knowledge of how the kernel works) ??. I have heard that Linux is a very popular OS for hardware control and embedded devices so I am guessing that this kind of thing must be possible to do somehow, but I have spent literally weeks on this so far and still have no concrete idea of how best to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how reading byte-by-byte helps you with fractional-character reception, unless it's that there is information encoded in the duration of intervals between characters, so you need to know the timing of when they are received.

At any rate, I do suspect you are going to need to make custom modifications to the serial port kernel driver; that's really not all that bad as a project goes, and you will learn a lot.  You will probably also need to change the configuration of the UART "chip" (really just a tiny corner of some larger device) to make it interrupt after only a single byte (ie emulate a 16450) instead of when it's typically 16-byte (emulating at 16550) buffer is partway full.  The code of the dos program might actually be a help there.  An alternative if the baud rate is not too fast would be to poll the hardware in the kernel or a realtime extension (or if it is really really slow as it might be on an HF radio link, maybe even in userspace)

If I'm right about needing to know the timing of the character reception, another option would be offload the reception to a micro-controller with dual UARTS (or even better, one UART and one USB interface).  You could then have the micro watch the serial stream, and output to the PC (either on the other serial port at a much faster baud rate, or on the USB) little packages of data that include one received character and a timestamp - or even have it decode the protocol for you.  The nice thing about this is that it would get you operating system independence, and would work on legacy free machines (byte-by-byte access is probably going to fail with an off-the-shelf USB-serial dongle).  You can probably even make it out of some cheap eval board, rather than having to manufacture any custom hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the last paragraph means nothing to me. I am an application developer and I have been thrown in at the deep end at work. I don't actually need to READ the bytes, but I need to be able to detect when they arrive so I can detect the 3.5 character length time delay that indicates end of transmission. Thanks though there is a lot of useful stuff in your reply for me to go off and research. I think I need to get some books...

Comment: I'd be very tempted to build a missing-pulse-detector then, you could do it with something like an arduino (or any of the USB-connected microcontrollers), or you could even do it with an analog circuit such as a 555 or even a resistor and capacitor, feeding into a status signal of a parallel port (if you still have one) which you could set up as a GPIO interrupt in the kernel and do a blocking read on the corresponding sysfs node.  Doing it in the kernel if you have a true serial port is of course possible too, but those are getting more and more scarce.

Comment: Seriously can you suggest a decent resource with which to get started with embedded linux. 2 months ago I had not even heard the expression.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as an embedded linux project.  Well, maybe the serial driver mods would resemble that (though you may actually  not want to use the serial driver as a base).  If the current version of your application needs to be future proof, I'd look strongly into the arduino or comparable as a helper board idea since you stop depending on details of the PC platform.  Though one thing you haven't mentioned is with what kind of latency you need to act (and how) after the 3.5 character break.  What is the baud rate, anyway?

Comment: 57.6K baudrate. I have no say in the hardware I will use. Ultimately the software that I am going to write must utilise CAN bus drivers and also TCP sockets - the serial port aspect is just one way that the hardware unit can receive modbus requests. What (roughly) defines what an embedded linux project is?